# Value assignment inside for-loop in Scala

Tags: scala, for-loop

Is there any difference between this code:

```
    for(term <- term_array) {
        val list = hashmap.get(term)
        ...
    }
```

and:

```
    for(term <- term_array; val list = hashmap.get(term)) {
        ...
    }
```

Inside the loop I'm changing the hashmap with something like this

```
hashmap.put(term, string :: list)
```

While checking for the head of `list` it seems to be outdated somehow when using the second code snippet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instantiating variables inside for loops makes sense if you want to use that variable the `for` statement, like:

```
for (i <- is; a = something; if (a)) {
   ...
}
```

And the reason why your list is outdated, is that this translates to a `foreach` call, such as:

```
term_array.foreach {
   term => val list= hashmap.get(term)
} foreach {
  ...
}
```

So when you reach ..., your hashmap has already been changed. The other example translates to:

```
term_array.foreach {
   term => val list= hashmap.get(term)
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 20):

The difference between the two is, that the first one is a definition which is created by pattern matching and the second one is a value inside a function literal. See [Programming in Scala, Section 23.1 For Expressions](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/for-expressions-revisited.html):

```
  for {
    p <- persons              // a generator
    n = p.name                // a definition
    if (n startsWith "To")    // a filter
  } yield n
```

You see the real difference when you compile sources with `scalac -Xprint:typer <filename>.scala`:

```
object X {
  val x1 = for (i <- (1 to 5); x = i*2) yield x
  val x2 = for (i <- (1 to 5)) yield { val x = i*2; x }
}
```

After code transforming by the compiler you will get something like this:

```
private[this] val x1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] =
  scala.this.Predef.intWrapper(1).to(5).map[(Int, Int), scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)]](((i: Int) => {
    val x: Int = i.*(2);
    scala.Tuple2.apply[Int, Int](i, x)
  }))(immutable.this.IndexedSeq.canBuildFrom[(Int, Int)]).map[Int, scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]]((
    (x$1: (Int, Int)) => (x$1: (Int, Int) @unchecked) match {
      case (_1: Int, _2: Int)(Int, Int)((i @ _), (x @ _)) => x
    }))(immutable.this.IndexedSeq.canBuildFrom[Int]);

private[this] val x2: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] =
  scala.this.Predef.intWrapper(1).to(5).map[Int, scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]](((i: Int) => {
    val x: Int = i.*(2);
    x
  }))(immutable.this.IndexedSeq.canBuildFrom[Int]);
```

This can be simplified to:

```
val x1 = (1 to 5).map {i =>
    val x: Int = i * 2
    (i, x)
  }.map {
    case (i, x) => x
  }

val x2 = (1 to 5).map {i =>
    val x = i * 2
    x
  }
```

Comment: Interesting. Could the transformation result be transformed into something more human readable?

Comment: @Suma not sure what you mean. The compiler output is valid Scala code (except some minor printing artifact issues). You can't get more high level or readable than that.

Comment: To make it easier to comprehend one could get rid of some valid, but not necessary parts, like type annotations, or `canBuildFroms` where not necessary, so that it looks more like something a human would write. I guess it is a bit mundane work, but perhaps it would make the core reason why the handling is different more obvious. I may try it later, if you do not think it is worth your effort.